# I cannot print to 6x4 photo paper

Tags: printing, brother

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with a wireless Brother MFC-J430W. When the printer is set up for A4, I can print from my laptop. However even when all settings on computer and on the printer are set to paper size 6X4 inches (or 15X10 cm on the printer), when I try to print a photo the printer ejects blank paper and renders the message that the paper size is wrong. I can print a test page on 6X4 paper OK, but not any photos.
I have tried CUPS drivers and driverless, all to no avail.
I have rebooted both printer (many times!) and the computer. Using Windows from another machine all is OK - the printer will do as it's told.

Has anyone any experience or ideas that may solve this problem?

Comment: You of course have the right Ubuntu driver for the Brother MFC-J430W printer?

Comment: Yes, I have installed the MFC-J430W driver from the Brother website. As I said, very puzzling as I can print a 6x4 paper with the Ubuntu test page. In A4, everything seems fine.